# html() not not appear to work for span element inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap navigation header with dropdown menus. I'm trying to append a word inside one of the dropdowns with html() without success. I tried append() and it's not working either. I'm not understanding since the list is static and NOT dynamic.

the dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg header-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         .'<span class="header-li">'.$Notifications.'</span>
         <i class="fas fa-caret-down header-icon"></i>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="" href="#">'.$Youhavenewnotifications.'</a></li>
         <hr>
          <li><a id="alist2345" href="#">
           Hi visitor from <span id="userRegion"></span>!
           We have many customers like you from <span id="userCity"></span>!
        </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

jQuery

```
$( window ).load(function() {
//get user location details
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {

 var userCity = response.city;
 var userRegion = response.region;

 //append to header
  $('#userRegion').html(userRegion);//does not work
  $('#userCity').html(userCity);//does not work
   //$('#alist2345').html(userRegion + userCity);//EDIT: THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE to show that this one works but it is obviously not the desire outcome

}, "jsonp");
});
```

Comment: Just for shiggles, try `console.log($('#userRegion').length)` and `console.log(userRegion)` inside the get callback.

Comment: Is the `.text()` method also not giving desired output? Just confirming!

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dschmzw7/2/

Comment: @barmar just did the same, https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/627290/

Comment: Try using https instead of http.

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr Why would that make a difference? She's able to get the response from the API, because the commented-out code works.

Comment: Touche Barmar, touche...

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the environment you're using to develop? Is ths a live web server, a LAMP stack on your local machine, etc... and maybe show us your order of dependencies. I'm just having a hard time seeing an error with your code and there is proof there is no error here. I suspect you have some sort of race condition with your UI. try wrapping your append in `settimeout()` and sleep for a second maybe even less. Just for the hell of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the kind efforts everybody!

I found the error and it was not my programming competences(phew). We are basically several heads in this project and one of the programmers uploaded a duplicate file on the desktop and strangely the application was fetching the data from that file instead of the one in the app folder...??

A deeper look in the console proved this to be true. I could see old data from the previous file and not the one I was working on.

Very strange behavior but when I deleted the duplicate file that my colleague previously uploaded for testing (and forgot to remove), everything started working as normal.

Very bizarre behavior but now it's fine.

Ps: if you know why this happened please let me know as I would like to know more on the subject!

Answer (score 2):

It does inject the `html` into the span as expected, but the last `html` insert, overwrites the previous changes.

```
$('#userRegion').html(userRegion);
$('#userCity').html(userCity);
$('#alist2345').html(userRegion + userCity); -- > This overwrites the `html` again ( and the span tags get replaced )
```

Remove the last statement and it should display as expected.

Otherwise you can try this as well..

```
$('#alist2345').html($('#alist2345').html() + userRegion + userCity);
```

Comment: @Sadie Please don't take offense. 90% of the questions are posted by totally incompetent programmers, and their problems are often incredibly dumb. There's no way to know that you're not one of them when the code looks like it.

Comment: @Sadie When a question is posted, the premise will be based on what we see. So provided an explanation on what might have caused the issue. I did not mean to offend you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are writing

```
$('#userRegion').html(userRegion);//does not work
$('#userCity').html(userCity);//does not work
```

and then clearing the whole anchor element with

```
$('#alist2345').html(userRegion + userCity);//works but not the desire outcome
```

Comment: I know. The last statement was just an example to show that when I append on the <a> element it works. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
$('#alist2345').html(userRegion + userCity);
```

And change the .html() to .text() because .html changes the "html" and .text() inserts a sting in the element.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $.get("https://ipinfo.io?token=yourtoken-goes-here", function (response) {
    var userCity = response.city;
    var userRegion = response.region;

    $('#userRegion').text(userRegion);
    $('#userCity').text(userCity);
  }, "jsonp")
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg header-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      .'<span class="header-li">'.$Notifications.'</span>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down header-icon"></i>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="" href="#">'.$Youhavenewnotifications.'</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a id="alist2345" href="#">Hi visitor from <span id="userRegion"></span>! We have many customers like you from <span id="userCity"></span>!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `$('#alist2345').html(userRegion + userCity);` is commented out.

Comment: You are Right. I teste die with .html(). It works fine, but .text() is the bettet Choice — you want to insert a string

Comment: I agree that it's best, but unless the region or city contains HTML tags it makes no difference.